# PayPal redirect does not keep session on return

Tags: php, apache, session, paypal

I am having an issue on our live server that the PayPal redirect doesn't keep the session on return. On the dev site on my local computer everything works without a problem.

Weird thing is that if I copy the link from "Cancel and return to " and paste it in the browser, the session is kept. But if I click on the link at the PayPal website, it is always lost.

Could that be a server configuration issue (PHP, Apache)?

Comment: Check the `SameSite` setting of your session cookie. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. That seems to have solved the issue. Is it save to use "ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'none');" or could that have any security implications?
Also, why did it work on localhost with strict and not on the live site?